# How to perform multiple NIntegrate in an efficient way?

Tags: numerical-integration

Consider the following function of 3 variables:

```
f[x_,y_,teta_] := Pflip[Sqrt[m^2 + x^2] Sqrt[M^2 + y^2] - 2 x y Cos[teta]]
```

where Pflip has been obtained by NIntegrating the function h (not written explicitly here because quite long and messy)

```
Pflip[s_]:= NIntegrate[h[s,th]Sin[th],{th,0,Pi}]
```

My goal is to perform two more numerical integrations (over teta and y), in order to get a function of x only:

```
f1[x_,y_]:= NIntegrate[f[x,y,teta]Sin[teta],{teta,0,Pi}]
f2[x_]:= NIntegrate[f1[x,y],{y,0,500}]
```

However Mathematica runs forever without providing any result if I just do as above and then try to plot f2[x].

I don't understand if this is due to the fact that the function h is complicated or my code is not the appropriate one to deal with multiple numerical integrations.

Comment: Have you tried using a single `NIntegrate`, e.g. something like `NIntegrate[h[s,th]Sin[th]Sin[teta], {th, 0, Pi}, {teta, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 500}]`? It is better to let `NIntegrate` deal with multiple dimensions instead of using `NIntegrate` on one dimension at a time.

Comment: you can use `EvaluationMonitor` to get an idea of progress: eg `f2[x_]:= NIntegrate[r=f1[x,y],{y,0,500},EvaluationMonitor:>Print[{y,r}]]`

Comment: All of your functions involving `NIntegrate` should be defined to take only numeric arguments, eg `f1[x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ]:=..` . (Be sure to `Clear` old definitions when you change that ).